# Bootstrap Navigation menu in Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

From [Build a Navigation Menu with Bootstrap 4](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-router-nested-routes-and-nested-auxiliary-routes-build-a-menu-navigation-system/), I have created a top navigation menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Angular Router</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" routerLinkActive="active">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="about">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="courses">Courses</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The problem is, when I click on a menu item like `home`, it is not shown as active. I haven't included `bootstrap.js`.

Instead of `bootstrap.js` & `jQuery`, what is the best way I can make selected menu as active in Angular 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `RouterLinkActive` directive on all `routerLink` items:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="courses" routerLinkActive="active">Courses</a></li>
```

`active` is `bootstrap`'s class which will highlight currently active link. You can read more about `RouterLinkActive` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html).

Comment: Sorry. It is not working. When menu is clicked it gets gray background, but after clicking on any field like Text field, the menu is not highlighted anymore.

Comment: @jaks Well, something else is causing problem for you then, check out Angular's official example, that's how it is done: https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview (`RouterLinkActive` directive is used in `app.component.ts`)

Comment: Do I need to use ng-bootstrap? I have included only bootstrap css cdn.

Comment: @jaks Don't think that's the issue here. You can try to make your own `css` class which will change the background of your active tab and then assign that class to `routerLinkActive` to check if bootstrap is the problem here.

Comment: Thanks a million. I defined my own CSS class and it is working.